# Solidworks vba Saving - error on object variable

Tags: vba, excel, solidworks

I'm trying to create a part in my code, and save it as a name the code generates. My save as command is not working and returning the error: "Object variable or with block variable not set" on the boolstatus line. Here's some of my code:

```
Dim instance As IModelDocExtension
Public swapp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Public swModdoc As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim Part As ModelDoc2
Dim MyForm As UserForm2
Public MyPath As String
Dim WholeName As String
Dim ProjNumber As String
Dim Checker As Object
Dim nErrors As Long
Dim nWarnings As Long
Dim longstatus As Long
Dim swInstance As SldWorks.ModelDocExtension
Sub main()

Dim Filter As String
Dim fileOptions As Long
Dim fileConfig As String
Dim fileDispName As String
Dim Checker As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim boolstatus As Boolean

Set swapp = Application.SldWorks
Filter = "SolidWorks Files (*.sldprt; *.sldasm; *.slddrw)|*.sldprt;*.sldasm;*.slddrw|Filter name (*.fil)|*.fil|All Files (*.*)|*.*"
PathName = swapp.GetOpenFileName("File Path to Save in", "", Filter, fileOptions, fileConfig, fileDispName)
MyPath = PathName
PathName = Dir(PathName)
MyPath = Left(MyPath, InStr(MyPath, PathName) - 1)

'call user form for input data
Load UserForm2
UserForm2.Show
UserForm2.Label4 = MyPath

End Sub

Sub Test(ProjNumber As String, FileType As String)
FileType = UserForm2.ComboBox1.value
ProjNumber = UserForm2.TextBox2.Text
Dim Index As Integer
Index = 1
    Dim WholeName As String
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = InStr(FileType, ".")
    FileType = Right(FileType, (Len(FileType) - pos))
    WholeName = MyPath & ProjNumber & "-0" & Index & "." & FileType
    Set Checker = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If Checker.FileExists(WholeName) = True Then
Index = Index + 1
Else
 MsgBox ("Saved As: " & WholeName)
 End If
Set Part = swapp.NewDocument(WholeName, 0, 0, 0)
Set Part = swapp.ActiveDoc
swapp.ActivateDoc2 "Part", False, longstatus
boolstatus = swModdoc.Save3(swSaveAsOptions_Silent, nErrors, nWarnings)
```

Why is the last line giving me an error? I guess I don't know how to go about saving in VBA.What is the best way to save the file created without getting an error?

Comment: `swModdoc.Save3`? - Need more code, can you  post complete code?

Comment: @0m3r yes, that line

Comment: You're not setting swModdoc. That's why it's giving out an error. Set to the return of swapp.ActivateDoc2 "Part", False, longstatus

Comment: It's a shame that this question is being put on hold. Some of the moderators don't know how to do their work. I don't like SO anymore.

Comment: @Jelly Thank you so much!! I had a feeling it had something to do with the moddoc. You rock!

Comment: @Jelly I changed these lines and still getting the same error. `Set swModdoc = swapp.ActivateDoc2("Part", False, longstatus)
boolstatus = swModdoc.Save3(swSaveAsOptions_Silent, nErrors, nWarnings)`

Comment: Can you give me the full error message?

Comment: I figured it out! I wasn't creating a new document correctly. Thanks @Jelly

Comment: @yagirljane: Great. Ask your SOLIDWORKS API questions in https://forum.solidworks.com/community/api. People here can be very nasty.